# Getting objects from model which aren't in M2M relation in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Models:

```
class Home(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='UserHome')

class UserHome(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    home = models.ForeignKey(Home, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_purchased = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

If there are 5 homes in this model and a particular user owns two of them, getting these two homes is simple:

```
homes = UserHome.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

That would return just the two homes the user owns. However, say if I wanted to list all homes in a template and gray out the homes that this user doesn't own, meaning it'd list 5 homes, 3 homes would be grayed out, 2 would be regularly displayed, are there any in-built ways to go about that?

Or would I have to use raw queries or compare the results from two queries (one for all homes, one for the user's homes)?

Comment: A small observation: with `datetime.now`, you need to provide the function itself (without `()`) and not the function's result in the model, otherwise the function will evaluated whenever your app starts only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do two queries:

```
user_homes = UserHome.objects.filter(user=request.user)
ids = [h.home.id for h in user_homes]
other_homes = Home.objects.exclude(id__in=ids)
```

And hopefully you can build your table off both lists.

Comment: Why "UserHome.objects.all()"? Since it's a M2M table it's going to result in the same home being repeated over and over (other users owning that same model of home).

Comment: Sorry, you are right. Wrote the answer too fast. I will correct it, but will take me a little longer. The answer will require more than one query.

Answer (score 1):

Guess you can achieve this with [`annotate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) in single query, something like this:

```
homes = Home.objects.annotate(is_current_user=Count(users=request.user)).all()
```

For homes that a related to current user `home.is_current_user` will be 1, and for all other homes it will be 0. So then you can iterate and check it:

```
for home in homes:
    if home.is_current_user:
        #display home as usual
    else:
        #display home greyed-out as not belonging to current user
```

The above should be adopted in template and use CSS style, ofc.